# SwiftUI: How to know change in the published var of an ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have a View which shows list of Toggle's based on the Model data. This model has a `@Published` variable which changes based toggle selection.

```
class Model: ObservableObject, Hashable {
      
    var id: String
    @Published var isSelected: Bool
    
    init(id: String, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
    ...
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var list: [Model]
    
    init() { ...}
    ...
    
    func save() {
        
    }
    
    func clear() {
        
    }
}


struct MyView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.list, id: \.self) { model in
                Toggle(model.id, isOn: $model.isSelected)
            }
            Button("Done") {
                viewModel.save()
            }
            Button("Clear") {
                viewModel.clear()
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, since I have array of models with @Publsihed,

- How to know if the user has changed any of the Toggles or not, so I can enable/disable Save button
- How to know list all toggles that are changed(i.e. models isSelected is changed), say like when I press save

Comment: Some observations: do not nest `ObservableObject` like you do, it creates problems.
Re-structure your code to have, `struct Model:...` with `var isSelected: Bool`, and in `ViewModel`, have `@Published var list: [Model]`

Comment: I would suggest to try and separate your questions (in different posts), so that they can be focused on just 1 thing and also they are easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this approach, to change the list of models `isSelected` property.

```
struct Model: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    var hasChanged: Bool = false // <--- here
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // for testing
    @Published var list: [Model] = [Model(id: "1", isSelected: false),
                                    Model(id: "2", isSelected: false),
                                    Model(id: "3", isSelected: true)]
    
     func save() {
         for mdl in list {
             if mdl.hasChanged {
                print("---> \(mdl.id) has changed")  // <-- here
             }
         }
     }
    
    func clear() {
        list = []
        print("---> clear list: \(list)")
    }
    
    func reset() {
        for i in list.indices {
            list[i].isSelected = false
        }
        print("---> reset list: \(list)")
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        MyView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State var hasChanged = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($viewModel.list) { $model in
                Toggle(model.id, isOn: $model.isSelected)
                    .onChange(of: model.isSelected) { val in  // <-- here
                        model.hasChanged.toggle()
                    }
            }
            Button("Save") {
                viewModel.save()
            }
            
            Button("Clear") {
                viewModel.clear()
            }
            Button("Reset") {
                viewModel.reset()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

If you want to count the number of times a particular `Model` has changed, then
simply add a counter to it, such as in this example code:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($viewModel.list) { $model in
                Toggle(model.id, isOn: $model.isSelected)
                    .onChange(of: model.isSelected) { val in  
                        model.changeCount += 1    // <-- here
                    }
            }
            Button("Save") {
                viewModel.save()
            }
            
            Button("Clear") {
                viewModel.clear()
            }
            Button("Reset") {
                viewModel.reset()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Model: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var isSelected: Bool 
    var changeCount: Int = 0  // <--- here
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // for testing
    @Published var list: [Model] = [Model(id: "1", isSelected: false),
                                    Model(id: "2", isSelected: false),
                                    Model(id: "3", isSelected: true)]
    
    func save() {
        for var mdl in list {
            print("---> \(mdl.id) has changed \(mdl.changeCount) times")  // <-- here
        }
    }
    
    func clear() {
        list = []
        print("---> clear list: \(list)")
    }
    
    func reset() {
        for i in list.indices {
            list[i].isSelected = false
        }
        print("---> reset list: \(list)")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is for the second question I believe. Here I need to know only the one's which are changed. One option is to have local copy and compare, but looking if there is any better approach than this. Maybe I should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution to your other question, `...to know only the one's which are changed...`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine how to track if the same object changed more than one time. (we can check it with the hasChanged exactly only for the first time )

Comment: The logic with my code is this: if the `isSelected` property of `Model` has changed (using the Toggle), 
the `hasChanged` will be set to `true`. If you change `isSelected` back to what it was,
the `hasChanged` will be set to `false`, since the  `Model` is now back to what it was originally, 
that is it has not changed. If you change the `isSelected` **again**, the `hasChanged` will be set to `true` **again**.
It works anytime, not just the first time.

Comment: updated my answer with a change counter.